# IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, thumbnail

Ao usar o comando

```
python generator video.mp4 2 150 80 10 thumbnails.jpg
```

tenho o seguinte retorno

```
Extracting 734 frames
  [####################################]  100%
Frames extracted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generator", line 90, in <module>
    generate_video_thumbnail(arguments)
  File "generator", line 39, in generate_video_thumbnail
    generate_sprite_from_frames(outputPrefix, columns, size, output)
  File "generator", line 62, in generate_sprite_from_frames
    images = [Image.open(filename) for filename in framesMap]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2312, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'c:\\users\\gpich\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpellfxjf728913fdda8373761ccb51c69fe51d5_00497.png'
```

Quando preciso gerar números menores de thumbnails ele gera sem problemas. Como faço para contornar esse problema?

O projeto está no github https://github.com/flavioribeiro/video-thumbnail-generator

abaixo o algumas funções relevantes para a geração

```
def generate_video_thumbnail(args):
    videoFileClip = VideoFileClip(args['<video>'])
    interval = int(args['<interval>'])
    size = (int(args['<width>']), int(args['<height>']))
    outputPrefix = get_output_prefix()
    generate_frames(videoFileClip, interval, outputPrefix, size)

    columns = int(args['<columns>'])
    output = args['<output>']
    generate_sprite_from_frames(outputPrefix, columns, size, output)


def extract_frame(videoFileClip, moment, outputPrefix, size, frameCount):
    output = outputPrefix + ("%05d.png" % frameCount)
    videoFileClip.save_frame(output, t=int(moment))
    resize_frame(output, size)

def resize_frame(filename, size):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image.save(filename)

def generate_sprite_from_frames(framesPath, columns, size, output):
    framesMap = sorted(glob.glob(framesPath + "*.png"))
    images = [Image.open(filename) for filename in framesMap]
    masterWidth = size[0] * columns
    masterHeight = size[1] * int(math.ceil(float(len(images)) / columns))
    finalImage = Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=(masterWidth, masterHeight), color=(0,0,0,0))
    merge_frames(images, finalImage, columns, size, output)
```

Comment: O seu erro parece ser bem simples: você tem muitos arquivos abertos ao mesmo tempo! Se você está gerando arquivos temporários com cada frame do vídeo e mantendo-os todos abertos, vai ser uma loucura mesmo (imagina um vídeo gravado em 30 quadros por segundo... com 10 minutos de vídeo vc tem 18 mil arquivos abertos!). Poste o código relevante aqui que fica mais fácil te ajudar (talvez da função `generate_video_thumbnail` seja suficiente?). Vc até pode manter o link do github, mas a pergunta tem que ter todos os detalhes.

Comment: Fiz as alterações, coloquei outras funções que eu creio que tenham relevância

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente, você está abrindo todos os arquivos para cada frame do vídeo. Ao fazer:

```
images = [Image.open(filename) for filename in framesMap]
```

Você está gerando uma lista (`images`) com os *handles* de cada arquivo retornado pelo `glob` da linha anterior. Por isso o erro.

> Como eu já mencionei em comentário, com um vídeo de 10 minutos gravado
>   a 30 FPS (frames por segundo), você chega facilmente a 18 mil arquivos
>   abertos!

Altere o seu código para processar arquivo por arquivo, dessa forma você não estoura o limite de *handles* do seu processo.

Primeiro, altere o código da função `generate_sprite_from_frames` assim:

```
def generate_sprite_from_frames(framesPath, columns, size, output):
    framesMap = sorted(glob.glob(framesPath + "*.png"))

    masterWidth = size[0] * columns
    masterHeight = size[1] * int(math.ceil(float(len(framesMap)) / columns))

    finalImage = Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=(masterWidth, masterHeight), color=(0,0,0,0))

    for col, filename in enumerate(framesMap):
        with Image.open(filename) as img:                              
            merge_frames_add(finalImage, image, col, size)
```

Você vai precisar fazer uma alteração também na função `merge_frames` para que ela possa abrir uma imagem existente do *spritesheet* com todos os frames e adicionar o frame atual a ela. E pode ser tudo em memória: a função `merge_frames_add` simplesmente copia o frame atual em `image` para a imagem do spritesheet em `finalImage` na região de interesse (ROI) de acordo com a coluna em `col`.

> Note que no exemplo acima eu intencionalmente mudei o nome para
>   `merge_frames_add` para denotar essa alteração.

Como você vai processar dentro de um bloco `width ... as ...`, a cada interação o `handle` do arquivo é fechado quando sai desse bloco e assim você não terá mais problemas. :)

Comment: Onde está sendo criada uma imagem no finalmage eu não deveria abrir a imagem já existente dentro da função?

Comment: Sim, se você optar por mantê-la em disco. Mas, como eu disse, vc pode fazer tudo em memória e só no final gravar em disco o spritesheet pronto. De fato, é mais eficiente dessa última forma porque você não fica reabrindo o arquivo a cada interação.

Comment: Está correto do jeito que está, digo, a cada with eu crio uma nova imagem?

Comment: hum... é igual a como vc faz hoje, só que uma imagem de cada vez.

Comment: removi a função merge_frames e coloquei ela na generate_sprite_from_frames (por questões de eu não saber mt python), aqui está o código final da função http://pastebin.com/ffc9FYbw

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! :) Aliás, parabéns pelo projeto. Boa sorte.